# Minikube: SQL Server running on local kubernetes with a volume on local machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes

## Context

- My OS is ubuntu 22.04.
- I use minikube. But I want something that looks like what I will have to deploy on prod.

## What I want

- SQL server
- Data of SQL server on a volume that is "binded" to a local directory of the hard drive  on my host machine

## What I did

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/mssql
sudo chmod +777 /mnt/mssql
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mon-volume-persistant
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/mssql
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mon-volume-persistant-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostname: mssqlinst
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 10001
      containers:
      - name: mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2G"
            cpu: "2000m"
          limits:
            memory: "2G"
            cpu: "2000m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_PID
          value: "Developer"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql
              key: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssqldb
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mon-volume-persistant-claim
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mssql
type: Opaque
data:
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.sql_sa_password | b64enc }}
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
  type: LoadBalancer
```

## What I get

The pod cannot start successfully.

```bash
kubectl describe pvc mon-volume-persistant-claim

Name:          mon-volume-persistant-claim
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Bound
Volume:        mon-volume-persistant
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:   meta.helm.sh/release-name: mssql
               meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
               pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       mssql-deployment-6477c9d6fb-jpbx4
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  31m   persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

```bash
kubectl describe pv mon-volume-persistant

Name:            mon-volume-persistant
Labels:          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:     meta.helm.sh/release-name: mssql
                 meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    local-storage
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/mon-volume-persistant-claim
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/mssql
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

```bash
kubectl logs mssql-deployment-6477c9d6fb-jpbx4 --all-containers

SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Error: The system directory [/.system] could not be created. File: LinuxDirectory.cpp:420 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]
```

I'm sure I am trying to solve a very common and simple problem, but I cannot find any clear and complete way to do it in the official K8S documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I muist remove the storage class and use `standard` instead.

Then I must go in the terminal of minikube container, and make `chown -R 10001:0 <my host folder>` as actually, from the point of view of kubernetes, the minikube container is the host of kubernetes. (see here: https://mycsharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2022/10/30/minikube-opt-mssql-bin-sqlservr-error-the-system-directory-system-could-not-be-created/)

Then, to have this folder mapped as is on my bare metal local folder, I must use `minikube mount`  command from my very machine. (see here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/)

## If you want to have everything persisting on your baremetal machine

- on your baremetal host computer, run this command:

```bash
minikube mount /mnt/mssql:/data/mssql --uid=10001
```

10001 is the user that is mentionned in the deployment. This command actually says to minikube that the container image that hosts kubernetes will map its folder `/data/mssql` to the very local folder `/mnt/mssql`, and that its local folder will belong to the user 10001. Then on the volume, the folder that is mentioned as the `hostPath` is the path of direct host... that is the minikube container. On this minikube container, we just defined that this folder will be `/data/mssql`

- deploy your helm chart or you K8S manifests

## If you want to have everything persisting only on your minikube container

- get the container_id of minikube:

```bash
docker ps
```

- Open a terminal on the minikube container:

```bash
run docker exec -it -u root <the previously discovered container_id>
```

- Give ownership to the user that will run deployed pods

```bash
chown -R 10001:0 /data/mssql
```

- deploy your helm chart or you K8S manifests
- expose the service from minikube to the local machine:

```bash
minikube tunnel
```

- list services:

```bash
kubectl get svc
```

- the IP address of your SQL Server is the one mentionned in External-IP